# Customize multiple progressive jpeg config in Fresco

Tags: android, fresco, progressive

The progressive jpeg config can be setted when initializing Fresco.

```
ImagePipelineConfig config = ImagePipelineConfig.newBuilder(context)
    .setProgressiveJpegConfig(progressiveJpegConfig)
    .build();
Fresco.initialize(context, config);
```

Now I want to loading the progressive jpeg in different scan quality, is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: What do you mean by "different scan quality"? Different progessive JPEG configs for different images?

Comment: There are two methods `getNextScanNumberToDecode` and `getQualityInfo` defined in `ProgressiveJpegConfig`. Like the [this](https://github.com/facebook/fresco/blob/master/imagepipeline/src/main/java/com/facebook/imagepipeline/decoder/SimpleProgressiveJpegConfig.java), and I want to customized the `GoodEnoughScanNumber` in different scenario.

Comment: for example, I want to set enough scan number to 5 in A-Acitvity, and set to 10 in B-Activity. Is there any way to achieve it?

Comment: I see. I've posted an answer below but out of curiosity: Why do you need to do that?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately, this is not supported right now.
However, a workaround that could help here:

- Create a delegating progressive JPEG config
- In Activity A, call `delegate.setConfig(configA)`
- In Activity B, call `delegate.setConfig(configB)`

This is not a perfect solution and if there are still image request from A in flight while B is active, you might end up in an inconsistent state, but it should work.

For proper support, either the ProducerFactory, DecodeProducer or the PJPEG config would need to be changed on the Fresco side. Pull requests are always welcome.

Comment: Sorry, I don't really understand how to create the delegating progressive JPEG config and to modify it. Can you provide the example with more detail. Thank you.